# Adding string before displaying json array

Tags: android, json, listview

I am new to android development. I managed to populate a listview with a string and a number coming from a JSON array.

I want to add a string (Available Quantity: ) before I display the number.

Can anyone help me with this?

It's being currently displayed as..

```
French Fries
1

Coke
4
```

I want to display it as:

```
Product: Coke

Quantity Available: 4
```

AllProductsActivity.java

```
public class AllProductsActivity extends ListActivity {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

// url to get all products list
private static String url_all_products = "http://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/search/?format=json&q=french%20fries&sort=n&max=250&offset=0&api_key=DEMO_KEY";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_PID = "offset";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

// products JSONArray
JSONArray products = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.all_products);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading products in Background Thread
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();

    // Get listview
    ListView lv = getListView();
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllProductsActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try {

            // products found
            // Getting Array of Products
            products = json.getJSONObject("list").getJSONArray("item");

            // looping through All Products
            for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);
                // Storing each json item in variable
                String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                productsList.add(map);
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        AllProductsActivity.this, productsList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                        TAG_NAME},
                        new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

Comment: post how you are parsing json...

Comment: Hey I added the JSONParser.java file.

Comment: ther is no code of parsing json...i mean how you are fetching string from json object ..that  code...

Comment: Sorry for that. Please let me know if this is not what you wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simple add up string when getting it from json like..

```
String id = "Quantity Available: "+c.getString(TAG_PID);
String name = "Product: "+c.getString(TAG_NAME);
```